# Change MacOS X mouse cursor Image

Tags: macos, mouse, mouseevent, osx-mountain-lion, osx-server

Is there any way to change Mac OSX mouse cursor image as I am recording a video in which I want to use a different image for Mac mouse cursor and I tried many software that only change size of the mouse cursor, but not the image. So how can I replace default MacOSX mouse cursor image on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `-(void) resetCursorRects` for a `NSView` subclass.  Something like this:

```
-(void) resetCursorRects {
    [super resetCursorRects];

    // define cursor image and cursorRects
    NSRect move = NSMakeRect((reg1UserStart + REGION_RESIZE_SIZE),REGION_Y_LOCATION, (self.reg1UserLength - (REGION_RESIZE_SIZE*2)), REGION_HEIGHT);
    NSRect resizeStart = NSMakeRect(self.reg1UserStart, REGION_Y_LOCATION, REGION_RESIZE_SIZE, REGION_HEIGHT);
    NSRect resizeEnd = NSMakeRect(((self.reg1UserStart + self.reg1UserLength) - REGION_RESIZE_SIZE), REGION_Y_LOCATION, REGION_RESIZE_SIZE, REGION_HEIGHT);

    [self addCursorRect:move cursor:[NSCursor openHandCursor]]; 
    [self addCursorRect:resizeStart cursor: [NSCursor resizeRightCursor]];
    [self addCursorRect:resizeEnd cursor:[NSCursor resizeLeftCursor]];
}
```

You have to define a `NSRect` that represents the area that changes the mouse cursor, and then you give it an NSCursor type.  This can be used to make custom cursors as well.

GW